# MMO RPG anime are great! Is this a new trend, or are there older anime in this genre?

Tags: anime-history

I got hooked on the lost-in-the-MMO genre with SAO (Sword Art Online), but I didn't even know it was a genre until a few weeks ago.  I caught up on Log Horizon, and now I'm watching Overlord.  Obviously, MMOs are a relatively new phenomenon, but approximately how old is this genre of anime?

I am curious because I'm about to go looking for more titles and I'd like to know how far back to search and/or when to stop looking.

Comment: .hack is probably one of the first, if not the first anime set in an MMO world. Also, don't forget Accel World

Comment: are you asking what the first MMORPG Themed anime/manga is? because currently how i am reading this is a recommendation request which is off topic

Comment: @Memor-X: It's asking for the start of the lost-in-MMO genre, not asking for recommendation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The earliest show I can think of where a character is trapped inside a video game is [.Hack//Sign](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.hack//Sign), which aired in 2002.

However, this isn't purely an anime feature - I read many books with similar situations, some dating before 2002. [Example 2002](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heir_Apparent_(novel)), [Example 1998](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/28695.City_of_Golden_Shadow)

Presumably this genre is a type of mutation of the ['Trapped in the TV' trope](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TrappedInTVLand).

It's an easy way to legitimize a fantasy world for an author, so it's become a common staple in teen/young fiction.

Whilst not exactly the same, there are earlier media like [The 1980's Dungeons & Dragons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dungeons_%26_Dragons_(TV_series)) cartoon that have characters magically transported to a fantasy world. Or even books like [Type Writer in the Sky (1940s)](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Literature/TypewriterInTheSky) in which characters are transported to a foreign land through the pages of a novel. **It's simply modernization of this trope.**

So, to answer your question - 2000s and onwards is a good starting point, but you might find similar shows with a slightly different approach earlier than that if you want.